# C: Writing a nested loop iterated by an interrupt/callback

Tags: c

Consider the following function:

```
void callback(){
  for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<20; j++)
      do_something(i,j);
}
```

I want `do_something(i,j)` to be called, and `i,j` incremented like a nested for loop, every time the `callback()` is called by an interrupt.

I have tried writing this using static variables as follows:

```
void callback(){
  static int i=0, j=0;

  do_something(i,j);

  if (j==20){
    j=0;
    if (i==100){
      i=0; // done
    } else i++;
  } else j++;

}
```

This isn't quite readable, especially given I need to do this for loops nested up to 6 levels. Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't a common coding pattern, there's no shorthand for it like `for` loops. The `if` statements are the way to do it.

Comment: You need to set `j` back to `0` whenever it reaches 20.

Comment: maybe `while (! (i==imax && j==jmax ... && z==zmax) )   do something;  logic to ++ the set with the correct rollover;`

Comment: @DaveS He can't use a `while` loop, because each call is supposed to be one iteration. The loop is outside of the function.

Comment: D'oh, yes, my end-of-work-day brain was thinking the `while` would somehow only do 1 iteration per invocation of the callback :) .  `if` does seem like the only way to approach this.  I'd move the do_something inside the `if` if there is any chance the number of callbacks will exceed the number of iterations that are needed.    So `if (! (i==imax && j==jmax ... && z==zmax) )   do something;  logic to ++ the set with the correct rollover;`

Comment: "This isn't quite readable" Maybe start with adopting a conventional coding style and formatting. It _would_ be quite readable if you used that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have lots of counters to increment, don't use separate variables, use an array to hold them. Then you can increment them odometer-style.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void do_something(int *vars, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d ", vars[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void callback() {
    static int vars[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    const int varmax[] = {3, 4, 5, 15, 10, 30};
    const int varcount = sizeof vars / sizeof *vars;

    do_something(vars, varcount);

    // increment each variable. When wrapping around, increment the next one
    for (int i = 0; i < varcount && ++vars[i] >= varmax[i]; i++) {
        vars[i] = 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 
2 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 
2 1 0 0 0 0 
0 2 0 0 0 0 
1 2 0 0 0 0 
2 2 0 0 0 0 
0 3 0 0 0 0 
1 3 0 0 0 0 
2 3 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 
2 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 
2 1 1 0 0 0 
0 2 1 0 0 0 
1 2 1 0 0 0 
2 2 1 0 0 0 
0 3 1 0 0 0 
1 3 1 0 0 0 
2 3 1 0 0 0 
0 0 2 0 0 0 
1 0 2 0 0 0 
2 0 2 0 0 0 
0 1 2 0 0 0 
1 1 2 0 0 0 
2 1 2 0 0 0 
0 2 2 0 0 0 
1 2 2 0 0 0 
2 2 2 0 0 0 
0 3 2 0 0 0 
1 3 2 0 0 0 
2 3 2 0 0 0 
0 0 3 0 0 0 
1 0 3 0 0 0 
2 0 3 0 0 0 
0 1 3 0 0 0 
1 1 3 0 0 0 
2 1 3 0 0 0 
0 2 3 0 0 0 
1 2 3 0 0 0 
2 2 3 0 0 0 
0 3 3 0 0 0 
1 3 3 0 0 0 
2 3 3 0 0 0 
0 0 4 0 0 0 
1 0 4 0 0 0 
2 0 4 0 0 0 
0 1 4 0 0 0 
1 1 4 0 0 0 
2 1 4 0 0 0 
0 2 4 0 0 0 
1 2 4 0 0 0 
2 2 4 0 0 0 
0 3 4 0 0 0 
1 3 4 0 0 0 
2 3 4 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 1 0 0 
2 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 0 
1 1 0 1 0 0 
2 1 0 1 0 0 
0 2 0 1 0 0 
1 2 0 1 0 0 
2 2 0 1 0 0 
0 3 0 1 0 0 
1 3 0 1 0 0 
2 3 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 0 
1 0 1 1 0 0 
2 0 1 1 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 0 
1 1 1 1 0 0 
2 1 1 1 0 0 
0 2 1 1 0 0 
1 2 1 1 0 0 
2 2 1 1 0 0 
0 3 1 1 0 0 
1 3 1 1 0 0 
2 3 1 1 0 0 
0 0 2 1 0 0 
1 0 2 1 0 0 
2 0 2 1 0 0 
0 1 2 1 0 0 
1 1 2 1 0 0 
2 1 2 1 0 0 
0 2 2 1 0 0 
1 2 2 1 0 0 
2 2 2 1 0 0 
0 3 2 1 0 0 
1 3 2 1 0 0 
2 3 2 1 0 0 
0 0 3 1 0 0 
1 0 3 1 0 0 
2 0 3 1 0 0 
0 1 3 1 0 0 
1 1 3 1 0 0 
2 1 3 1 0 0 
0 2 3 1 0 0 
1 2 3 1 0 0 
2 2 3 1 0 0 
0 3 3 1 0 0 
1 3 3 1 0 0 
2 3 3 1 0 0 
0 0 4 1 0 0 
1 0 4 1 0 0 
2 0 4 1 0 0 
0 1 4 1 0 0 
1 1 4 1 0 0 
2 1 4 1 0 0 
0 2 4 1 0 0 
1 2 4 1 0 0 
2 2 4 1 0 0 
0 3 4 1 0 0 
1 3 4 1 0 0 
2 3 4 1 0 0 
0 0 0 2 0 0 
1 0 0 2 0 0 
2 0 0 2 0 0 
0 1 0 2 0 0 
1 1 0 2 0 0 
2 1 0 2 0 0 
0 2 0 2 0 0 
1 2 0 2 0 0 
2 2 0 2 0 0 
0 3 0 2 0 0 
1 3 0 2 0 0 
2 3 0 2 0 0 
0 0 1 2 0 0 
1 0 1 2 0 0 
2 0 1 2 0 0 
0 1 1 2 0 0 
1 1 1 2 0 0 
2 1 1 2 0 0 
0 2 1 2 0 0 
1 2 1 2 0 0 
2 2 1 2 0 0 
0 3 1 2 0 0 
1 3 1 2 0 0 
2 3 1 2 0 0 
0 0 2 2 0 0 
1 0 2 2 0 0 
2 0 2 2 0 0 
0 1 2 2 0 0 
1 1 2 2 0 0 
2 1 2 2 0 0 
0 2 2 2 0 0 
1 2 2 2 0 0 
2 2 2 2 0 0 
0 3 2 2 0 0 
1 3 2 2 0 0 
2 3 2 2 0 0 
0 0 3 2 0 0 
1 0 3 2 0 0 
2 0 3 2 0 0 
0 1 3 2 0 0 
1 1 3 2 0 0 
2 1 3 2 0 0 
0 2 3 2 0 0 
1 2 3 2 0 0 
2 2 3 2 0 0 
0 3 3 2 0 0 
1 3 3 2 0 0 
2 3 3 2 0 0 
0 0 4 2 0 0 
1 0 4 2 0 0 
2 0 4 2 0 0 
0 1 4 2 0 0 
1 1 4 2 0 0 
2 1 4 2 0 0 
0 2 4 2 0 0 
1 2 4 2 0 0 
2 2 4 2 0 0 
0 3 4 2 0 0 
1 3 4 2 0 0 
2 3 4 2 0 0 
0 0 0 3 0 0 
1 0 0 3 0 0 
2 0 0 3 0 0 
0 1 0 3 0 0 
1 1 0 3 0 0 
2 1 0 3 0 0 
0 2 0 3 0 0 
1 2 0 3 0 0 
2 2 0 3 0 0 
0 3 0 3 0 0 
1 3 0 3 0 0 
2 3 0 3 0 0 
0 0 1 3 0 0 
1 0 1 3 0 0 
2 0 1 3 0 0 
0 1 1 3 0 0 
1 1 1 3 0 0 
2 1 1 3 0 0 
0 2 1 3 0 0 
1 2 1 3 0 0 
2 2 1 3 0 0 
0 3 1 3 0 0 
1 3 1 3 0 0 
2 3 1 3 0 0 
0 0 2 3 0 0 
1 0 2 3 0 0 
2 0 2 3 0 0 
0 1 2 3 0 0 
1 1 2 3 0 0 
2 1 2 3 0 0 
0 2 2 3 0 0 
1 2 2 3 0 0 
2 2 2 3 0 0 
0 3 2 3 0 0 
1 3 2 3 0 0 
2 3 2 3 0 0 
0 0 3 3 0 0 
1 0 3 3 0 0 
2 0 3 3 0 0 
0 1 3 3 0 0 
1 1 3 3 0 0 
2 1 3 3 0 0 
0 2 3 3 0 0 
1 2 3 3 0 0 
2 2 3 3 0 0 
0 3 3 3 0 0 
1 3 3 3 0 0 
2 3 3 3 0 0 
0 0 4 3 0 0 
1 0 4 3 0 0 
2 0 4 3 0 0 
0 1 4 3 0 0 
1 1 4 3 0 0 
2 1 4 3 0 0 
0 2 4 3 0 0 
1 2 4 3 0 0 
2 2 4 3 0 0 
0 3 4 3 0 0 
1 3 4 3 0 0 
2 3 4 3 0 0 
0 0 0 4 0 0 
1 0 0 4 0 0 
2 0 0 4 0 0 
0 1 0 4 0 0 
1 1 0 4 0 0 
2 1 0 4 0 0 
0 2 0 4 0 0 
1 2 0 4 0 0 
2 2 0 4 0 0 
0 3 0 4 0 0 
1 3 0 4 0 0 
2 3 0 4 0 0 
0 0 1 4 0 0 
1 0 1 4 0 0 
2 0 1 4 0 0 
0 1 1 4 0 0 
1 1 1 4 0 0 
2 1 1 4 0 0 
0 2 1 4 0 0 
1 2 1 4 0 0 
2 2 1 4 0 0 
0 3 1 4 0 0 
1 3 1 4 0 0 
2 3 1 4 0 0 
0 0 2 4 0 0 
1 0 2 4 0 0 
2 0 2 4 0 0 
0 1 2 4 0 0 
1 1 2 4 0 0 
2 1 2 4 0 0 
0 2 2 4 0 0 
1 2 2 4 0 0 
2 2 2 4 0 0 
0 3 2 4 0 0 
1 3 2 4 0 0 
2 3 2 4 0 0 
0 0 3 4 0 0 
1 0 3 4 0 0 
2 0 3 4 0 0 
0 1 3 4 0 0 
1 1 3 4 0 0 
2 1 3 4 0 0 
0 2 3 4 0 0 
1 2 3 4 0 0 
2 2 3 4 0 0 
0 3 3 4 0 0 
1 3 3 4 0 0 
2 3 3 4 0 0 
0 0 4 4 0 0 
1 0 4 4 0 0 
2 0 4 4 0 0 
0 1 4 4 0 0 
1 1 4 4 0 0 
2 1 4 4 0 0 
0 2 4 4 0 0 
1 2 4 4 0 0 
2 2 4 4 0 0 
0 3 4 4 0 0 
1 3 4 4 0 0 
2 3 4 4 0 0 
0 0 0 5 0 0 
1 0 0 5 0 0 
2 0 0 5 0 0 
0 1 0 5 0 0 
1 1 0 5 0 0 
2 1 0 5 0 0 
0 2 0 5 0 0 
1 2 0 5 0 0 
2 2 0 5 0 0 
0 3 0 5 0 0 
1 3 0 5 0 0 
2 3 0 5 0 0 
0 0 1 5 0 0 
1 0 1 5 0 0 
2 0 1 5 0 0 
0 1 1 5 0 0 
1 1 1 5 0 0 
2 1 1 5 0 0 
0 2 1 5 0 0 
1 2 1 5 0 0 
2 2 1 5 0 0 
0 3 1 5 0 0 
1 3 1 5 0 0 
2 3 1 5 0 0 
0 0 2 5 0 0 
1 0 2 5 0 0 
2 0 2 5 0 0 
0 1 2 5 0 0 
1 1 2 5 0 0 
2 1 2 5 0 0 
0 2 2 5 0 0 
1 2 2 5 0 0 
2 2 2 5 0 0 
0 3 2 5 0 0 
1 3 2 5 0 0 
2 3 2 5 0 0 
0 0 3 5 0 0 
1 0 3 5 0 0 
2 0 3 5 0 0 
0 1 3 5 0 0 
1 1 3 5 0 0 
2 1 3 5 0 0 
0 2 3 5 0 0 
1 2 3 5 0 0 
2 2 3 5 0 0 
0 3 3 5 0 0 
1 3 3 5 0 0 
2 3 3 5 0 0 
0 0 4 5 0 0 
1 0 4 5 0 0 
2 0 4 5 0 0 
0 1 4 5 0 0 
1 1 4 5 0 0 
2 1 4 5 0 0 
0 2 4 5 0 0 
1 2 4 5 0 0 
2 2 4 5 0 0 
0 3 4 5 0 0 
1 3 4 5 0 0 
2 3 4 5 0 0 
0 0 0 6 0 0 
1 0 0 6 0 0 
2 0 0 6 0 0 
0 1 0 6 0 0 
1 1 0 6 0 0 
2 1 0 6 0 0 
0 2 0 6 0 0 
1 2 0 6 0 0 
2 2 0 6 0 0 
0 3 0 6 0 0 
1 3 0 6 0 0 
2 3 0 6 0 0 
0 0 1 6 0 0 
1 0 1 6 0 0 
2 0 1 6 0 0 
0 1 1 6 0 0 
1 1 1 6 0 0 
2 1 1 6 0 0 
0 2 1 6 0 0 
1 2 1 6 0 0 
2 2 1 6 0 0 
0 3 1 6 0 0 
1 3 1 6 0 0 
2 3 1 6 0 0 
0 0 2 6 0 0 
1 0 2 6 0 0 
2 0 2 6 0 0 
0 1 2 6 0 0 
1 1 2 6 0 0 
2 1 2 6 0 0 
0 2 2 6 0 0 
1 2 2 6 0 0 
2 2 2 6 0 0 
0 3 2 6 0 0 
1 3 2 6 0 0 
2 3 2 6 0 0 
0 0 3 6 0 0 
1 0 3 6 0 0 
2 0 3 6 0 0 
0 1 3 6 0 0 
1 1 3 6 0 0 
2 1 3 6 0 0 
0 2 3 6 0 0 
1 2 3 6 0 0 
2 2 3 6 0 0 
0 3 3 6 0 0 
1 3 3 6 0 0 
2 3 3 6 0 0 
0 0 4 6 0 0 
1 0 4 6 0 0 
2 0 4 6 0 0 
0 1 4 6 0 0 
1 1 4 6 0 0 
2 1 4 6 0 0 
0 2 4 6 0 0 
1 2 4 6 0 0 
2 2 4 6 0 0 
0 3 4 6 0 0 
1 3 4 6 0 0 
2 3 4 6 0 0 
0 0 0 7 0 0 
1 0 0 7 0 0 
2 0 0 7 0 0 
0 1 0 7 0 0 
1 1 0 7 0 0 
2 1 0 7 0 0 
0 2 0 7 0 0 
1 2 0 7 0 0 
2 2 0 7 0 0 
0 3 0 7 0 0 
1 3 0 7 0 0 
2 3 0 7 0 0 
0 0 1 7 0 0 
1 0 1 7 0 0 
2 0 1 7 0 0 
0 1 1 7 0 0 
1 1 1 7 0 0 
2 1 1 7 0 0 
0 2 1 7 0 0 
1 2 1 7 0 0 
2 2 1 7 0 0 
0 3 1 7 0 0 
1 3 1 7 0 0 
2 3 1 7 0 0 
0 0 2 7 0 0 
1 0 2 7 0 0 
2 0 2 7 0 0 
0 1 2 7 0 0 
1 1 2 7 0 0 
2 1 2 7 0 0 
0 2 2 7 0 0 
1 2 2 7 0 0 
2 2 2 7 0 0 
0 3 2 7 0 0 
1 3 2 7 0 0 
2 3 2 7 0 0 
0 0 3 7 0 0 
1 0 3 7 0 0 
2 0 3 7 0 0 
0 1 3 7 0 0 
1 1 3 7 0 0 
2 1 3 7 0 0 
0 2 3 7 0 0 
1 2 3 7 0 0 
2 2 3 7 0 0 
0 3 3 7 0 0 
1 3 3 7 0 0 
2 3 3 7 0 0 
0 0 4 7 0 0 
1 0 4 7 0 0 
2 0 4 7 0 0 
0 1 4 7 0 0 
1 1 4 7 0 0 
2 1 4 7 0 0 
0 2 4 7 0 0 
1 2 4 7 0 0 
2 2 4 7 0 0 
0 3 4 7 0 0 
1 3 4 7 0 0 
2 3 4 7 0 0 
0 0 0 8 0 0 
1 0 0 8 0 0 
2 0 0 8 0 0 
0 1 0 8 0 0 
1 1 0 8 0 0 
2 1 0 8 0 0 
0 2 0 8 0 0 
1 2 0 8 0 0 
2 2 0 8 0 0 
0 3 0 8 0 0 
1 3 0 8 0 0 
2 3 0 8 0 0 
0 0 1 8 0 0 
1 0 1 8 0 0 
2 0 1 8 0 0 
0 1 1 8 0 0 
1 1 1 8 0 0 
2 1 1 8 0 0 
0 2 1 8 0 0 
1 2 1 8 0 0 
2 2 1 8 0 0 
0 3 1 8 0 0 
1 3 1 8 0 0 
2 3 1 8 0 0 
0 0 2 8 0 0 
1 0 2 8 0 0 
2 0 2 8 0 0 
0 1 2 8 0 0 
1 1 2 8 0 0 
2 1 2 8 0 0 
0 2 2 8 0 0 
1 2 2 8 0 0 
2 2 2 8 0 0 
0 3 2 8 0 0 
1 3 2 8 0 0 
2 3 2 8 0 0 
0 0 3 8 0 0 
1 0 3 8 0 0 
2 0 3 8 0 0 
0 1 3 8 0 0 
1 1 3 8 0 0 
2 1 3 8 0 0 
0 2 3 8 0 0 
1 2 3 8 0 0 
2 2 3 8 0 0 
0 3 3 8 0 0 
1 3 3 8 0 0 
2 3 3 8 0 0 
0 0 4 8 0 0 
1 0 4 8 0 0 
2 0 4 8 0 0 
0 1 4 8 0 0 
1 1 4 8 0 0 
2 1 4 8 0 0 
0 2 4 8 0 0 
1 2 4 8 0 0 
2 2 4 8 0 0 
0 3 4 8 0 0 
1 3 4 8 0 0 
2 3 4 8 0 0 
0 0 0 9 0 0 
1 0 0 9 0 0 
2 0 0 9 0 0 
0 1 0 9 0 0 
1 1 0 9 0 0 
2 1 0 9 0 0 
0 2 0 9 0 0 
1 2 0 9 0 0 
2 2 0 9 0 0 
0 3 0 9 0 0 
1 3 0 9 0 0 
2 3 0 9 0 0 
0 0 1 9 0 0 
1 0 1 9 0 0 
2 0 1 9 0 0 
0 1 1 9 0 0 
1 1 1 9 0 0 
2 1 1 9 0 0 
0 2 1 9 0 0 
1 2 1 9 0 0 
2 2 1 9 0 0 
0 3 1 9 0 0 
1 3 1 9 0 0 
2 3 1 9 0 0 
0 0 2 9 0 0 
1 0 2 9 0 0 
2 0 2 9 0 0 
0 1 2 9 0 0 
1 1 2 9 0 0 
2 1 2 9 0 0 
0 2 2 9 0 0 
1 2 2 9 0 0 
2 2 2 9 0 0 
0 3 2 9 0 0 
1 3 2 9 0 0 
2 3 2 9 0 0 
0 0 3 9 0 0 
1 0 3 9 0 0 
2 0 3 9 0 0 
0 1 3 9 0 0 
1 1 3 9 0 0 
2 1 3 9 0 0 
0 2 3 9 0 0 
1 2 3 9 0 0 
2 2 3 9 0 0 
0 3 3 9 0 0 
1 3 3 9 0 0 
2 3 3 9 0 0 
0 0 4 9 0 0 
1 0 4 9 0 0 
2 0 4 9 0 0 
0 1 4 9 0 0 
1 1 4 9 0 0 
2 1 4 9 0 0 
0 2 4 9 0 0 
1 2 4 9 0 0 
2 2 4 9 0 0 
0 3 4 9 0 0 
1 3 4 9 0 0 
2 3 4 9 0 0 
0 0 0 10 0 0 
1 0 0 10 0 0 
2 0 0 10 0 0 
0 1 0 10 0 0 
1 1 0 10 0 0 
2 1 0 10 0 0 
0 2 0 10 0 0 
1 2 0 10 0 0 
2 2 0 10 0 0 
0 3 0 10 0 0 
1 3 0 10 0 0 
2 3 0 10 0 0 
0 0 1 10 0 0 
1 0 1 10 0 0 
2 0 1 10 0 0 
0 1 1 10 0 0 
1 1 1 10 0 0 
2 1 1 10 0 0 
0 2 1 10 0 0 
1 2 1 10 0 0 
2 2 1 10 0 0 
0 3 1 10 0 0 
1 3 1 10 0 0 
2 3 1 10 0 0 
0 0 2 10 0 0 
1 0 2 10 0 0 
2 0 2 10 0 0 
0 1 2 10 0 0 
1 1 2 10 0 0 
2 1 2 10 0 0 
0 2 2 10 0 0 
1 2 2 10 0 0 
2 2 2 10 0 0 
0 3 2 10 0 0 
1 3 2 10 0 0 
2 3 2 10 0 0 
0 0 3 10 0 0 
1 0 3 10 0 0 
2 0 3 10 0 0 
0 1 3 10 0 0 
1 1 3 10 0 0 
2 1 3 10 0 0 
0 2 3 10 0 0 
1 2 3 10 0 0 
2 2 3 10 0 0 
0 3 3 10 0 0 
1 3 3 10 0 0 
2 3 3 10 0 0 
0 0 4 10 0 0 
1 0 4 10 0 0 
2 0 4 10 0 0 
0 1 4 10 0 0 
1 1 4 10 0 0 
2 1 4 10 0 0 
0 2 4 10 0 0 
1 2 4 10 0 0 
2 2 4 10 0 0 
0 3 4 10 0 0 
1 3 4 10 0 0 
2 3 4 10 0 0 
0 0 0 11 0 0 
1 0 0 11 0 0 
2 0 0 11 0 0 
0 1 0 11 0 0 
1 1 0 11 0 0 
2 1 0 11 0 0 
0 2 0 11 0 0 
1 2 0 11 0 0 
2 2 0 11 0 0 
0 3 0 11 0 0 
1 3 0 11 0 0 
2 3 0 11 0 0 
0 0 1 11 0 0 
1 0 1 11 0 0 
2 0 1 11 0 0 
0 1 1 11 0 0 
1 1 1 11 0 0 
2 1 1 11 0 0 
0 2 1 11 0 0 
1 2 1 11 0 0 
2 2 1 11 0 0 
0 3 1 11 0 0 
1 3 1 11 0 0 
2 3 1 11 0 0 
0 0 2 11 0 0 
1 0 2 11 0 0 
2 0 2 11 0 0 
0 1 2 11 0 0 
1 1 2 11 0 0 
2 1 2 11 0 0 
0 2 2 11 0 0 
1 2 2 11 0 0 
2 2 2 11 0 0 
0 3 2 11 0 0 
1 3 2 11 0 0 
2 3 2 11 0 0 
0 0 3 11 0 0 
1 0 3 11 0 0 
2 0 3 11 0 0 
0 1 3 11 0 0 
1 1 3 11 0 0 
2 1 3 11 0 0 
0 2 3 11 0 0 
1 2 3 11 0 0 
2 2 3 11 0 0 
0 3 3 11 0 0 
1 3 3 11 0 0 
2 3 3 11 0 0 
0 0 4 11 0 0 
1 0 4 11 0 0 
2 0 4 11 0 0 
0 1 4 11 0 0 
1 1 4 11 0 0 
2 1 4 11 0 0 
0 2 4 11 0 0 
1 2 4 11 0 0 
2 2 4 11 0 0 
0 3 4 11 0 0 
1 3 4 11 0 0 
2 3 4 11 0 0 
0 0 0 12 0 0 
1 0 0 12 0 0 
2 0 0 12 0 0 
0 1 0 12 0 0 
1 1 0 12 0 0 
2 1 0 12 0 0 
0 2 0 12 0 0 
1 2 0 12 0 0 
2 2 0 12 0 0 
0 3 0 12 0 0 
1 3 0 12 0 0 
2 3 0 12 0 0 
0 0 1 12 0 0 
1 0 1 12 0 0 
2 0 1 12 0 0 
0 1 1 12 0 0 
1 1 1 12 0 0 
2 1 1 12 0 0 
0 2 1 12 0 0 
1 2 1 12 0 0 
2 2 1 12 0 0 
0 3 1 12 0 0 
1 3 1 12 0 0 
2 3 1 12 0 0 
0 0 2 12 0 0 
1 0 2 12 0 0 
2 0 2 12 0 0 
0 1 2 12 0 0 
1 1 2 12 0 0 
2 1 2 12 0 0 
0 2 2 12 0 0 
1 2 2 12 0 0 
2 2 2 12 0 0 
0 3 2 12 0 0 
1 3 2 12 0 0 
2 3 2 12 0 0 
0 0 3 12 0 0 
1 0 3 12 0 0 
2 0 3 12 0 0 
0 1 3 12 0 0 
1 1 3 12 0 0 
2 1 3 12 0 0 
0 2 3 12 0 0 
1 2 3 12 0 0 
2 2 3 12 0 0 
0 3 3 12 0 0 
1 3 3 12 0 0 
2 3 3 12 0 0 
0 0 4 12 0 0 
1 0 4 12 0 0 
2 0 4 12 0 0 
0 1 4 12 0 0 
1 1 4 12 0 0 
2 1 4 12 0 0 
0 2 4 12 0 0 
1 2 4 12 0 0 
2 2 4 12 0 0 
0 3 4 12 0 0 
1 3 4 12 0 0 
2 3 4 12 0 0 
0 0 0 13 0 0 
1 0 0 13 0 0 
2 0 0 13 0 0 
0 1 0 13 0 0 
1 1 0 13 0 0 
2 1 0 13 0 0 
0 2 0 13 0 0 
1 2 0 13 0 0 
2 2 0 13 0 0 
0 3 0 13 0 0 
1 3 0 13 0 0 
2 3 0 13 0 0 
0 0 1 13 0 0 
1 0 1 13 0 0 
2 0 1 13 0 0 
0 1 1 13 0 0 
1 1 1 13 0 0 
2 1 1 13 0 0 
0 2 1 13 0 0 
1 2 1 13 0 0 
2 2 1 13 0 0 
0 3 1 13 0 0 
1 3 1 13 0 0 
2 3 1 13 0 0 
0 0 2 13 0 0 
1 0 2 13 0 0 
2 0 2 13 0 0 
0 1 2 13 0 0 
1 1 2 13 0 0 
2 1 2 13 0 0 
0 2 2 13 0 0 
1 2 2 13 0 0 
2 2 2 13 0 0 
0 3 2 13 0 0 
1 3 2 13 0 0 
2 3 2 13 0 0 
0 0 3 13 0 0 
1 0 3 13 0 0 
2 0 3 13 0 0 
0 1 3 13 0 0 
1 1 3 13 0 0 
2 1 3 13 0 0 
0 2 3 13 0 0 
1 2 3 13 0 0 
2 2 3 13 0 0 
0 3 3 13 0 0 
1 3 3 13 0 0 
2 3 3 13 0 0 
0 0 4 13 0 0 
1 0 4 13 0 0 
2 0 4 13 0 0 
0 1 4 13 0 0 
1 1 4 13 0 0 
2 1 4 13 0 0 
0 2 4 13 0 0 
1 2 4 13 0 0 
2 2 4 13 0 0 
0 3 4 13 0 0 
1 3 4 13 0 0 
2 3 4 13 0 0 
0 0 0 14 0 0 
1 0 0 14 0 0 
2 0 0 14 0 0 
0 1 0 14 0 0 
1 1 0 14 0 0 
2 1 0 14 0 0 
0 2 0 14 0 0 
1 2 0 14 0 0 
2 2 0 14 0 0 
0 3 0 14 0 0 
1 3 0 14 0 0 
2 3 0 14 0 0 
0 0 1 14 0 0 
1 0 1 14 0 0 
2 0 1 14 0 0 
0 1 1 14 0 0 
1 1 1 14 0 0 
2 1 1 14 0 0 
0 2 1 14 0 0 
1 2 1 14 0 0 
2 2 1 14 0 0 
0 3 1 14 0 0 
1 3 1 14 0 0 
2 3 1 14 0 0 
0 0 2 14 0 0 
1 0 2 14 0 0 
2 0 2 14 0 0 
0 1 2 14 0 0 
1 1 2 14 0 0 
2 1 2 14 0 0 
0 2 2 14 0 0 
1 2 2 14 0 0 
2 2 2 14 0 0 
0 3 2 14 0 0 
1 3 2 14 0 0 
2 3 2 14 0 0 
0 0 3 14 0 0 
1 0 3 14 0 0 
2 0 3 14 0 0 
0 1 3 14 0 0 
1 1 3 14 0 0 
2 1 3 14 0 0 
0 2 3 14 0 0 
1 2 3 14 0 0 
2 2 3 14 0 0 
0 3 3 14 0 0 
1 3 3 14 0 0 
2 3 3 14 0 0 
0 0 4 14 0 0 
1 0 4 14 0 0 
2 0 4 14 0 0 
0 1 4 14 0 0 
1 1 4 14 0 0 
2 1 4 14 0 0 
0 2 4 14 0 0 
1 2 4 14 0 0 
2 2 4 14 0 0 
0 3 4 14 0 0 
1 3 4 14 0 0 
2 3 4 14 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 
2 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 1 0 
1 1 0 0 1 0 
2 1 0 0 1 0 
0 2 0 0 1 0 
1 2 0 0 1 0 
2 2 0 0 1 0 
0 3 0 0 1 0 
1 3 0 0 1 0 
2 3 0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 1 0 
2 0 1 0 1 0 
0 1 1 0 1 0 
1 1 1 0 1 0 
2 1 1 0 1 0 
0 2 1 0 1 0 
1 2 1 0 1 0 
2 2 1 0 1 0 
0 3 1 0 1 0 
1 3 1 0 1 0 
2 3 1 0 1 0 
0 0 2 0 1 0 
1 0 2 0 1 0 
2 0 2 0 1 0 
0 1 2 0 1 0 
1 1 2 0 1 0 
2 1 2 0 1 0 
0 2 2 0 1 0 
1 2 2 0 1 0 
2 2 2 0 1 0 
0 3 2 0 1 0 
1 3 2 0 1 0 
2 3 2 0 1 0 
0 0 3 0 1 0 
1 0 3 0 1 0 
2 0 3 0 1 0 
0 1 3 0 1 0 
1 1 3 0 1 0 
2 1 3 0 1 0 
0 2 3 0 1 0 
1 2 3 0 1 0 
2 2 3 0 1 0 
0 3 3 0 1 0 
1 3 3 0 1 0 
2 3 3 0 1 0 
0 0 4 0 1 0 
1 0 4 0 1 0 
2 0 4 0 1 0 
0 1 4 0 1 0 
1 1 4 0 1 0 
2 1 4 0 1 0 
0 2 4 0 1 0 
1 2 4 0 1 0 
2 2 4 0 1 0 
0 3 4 0 1 0 
1 3 4 0 1 0 
2 3 4 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 
1 0 0 1 1 0 
2 0 0 1 1 0 
0 1 0 1 1 0 
1 1 0 1 1 0 
2 1 0 1 1 0 
0 2 0 1 1 0 
1 2 0 1 1 0 
2 2 0 1 1 0 
0 3 0 1 1 0 
1 3 0 1 1 0 
2 3 0 1 1 0 
0 0 1 1 1 0 
1 0 1 1 1 0 
2 0 1 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 1 1 0 
2 1 1 1 1 0 
0 2 1 1 1 0 
1 2 1 1 1 0 
2 2 1 1 1 0 
0 3 1 1 1 0 
1 3 1 1 1 0 
2 3 1 1 1 0 
0 0 2 1 1 0 
1 0 2 1 1 0 
2 0 2 1 1 0 
0 1 2 1 1 0 
1 1 2 1 1 0 
2 1 2 1 1 0 
0 2 2 1 1 0 
1 2 2 1 1 0 
2 2 2 1 1 0 
0 3 2 1 1 0 
1 3 2 1 1 0 
2 3 2 1 1 0 
0 0 3 1 1 0 
1 0 3 1 1 0 
2 0 3 1 1 0 
0 1 3 1 1 0
```

Comment: This looks quite elegant. I'm struggling to understand `varcount && ++vars[i] >= varmax[i]`. Can you explain it?

Comment: It increments `vars[i]`. If that goes over the corresponding limit, the loop body is entered to reset it to 0. Then we increment `i` to go to the next variable and repeat this. So it's like an odometer flipping from 2999 to 3000.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Such an elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like:

```
void callback(void){
    static int i=0, j=0;

    do_something(i,j);

    ++ j;
    if (j >= 20)
    {
        j = 0;
        ++ i;
        if (i >= 100)
        {
            // That's all folks!
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear what should happen if the callback gets called after you've iterated all of your "loops". I've made it so that it starts again from (0,0).

Comment: This is pretty much the standard way to write code like this, so I'd say that this is the correct answer. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to look like nested `for` loops, write nested `for` loops:

```
void callback(void)
{
    goto Resume;

    static int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            return;
Resume:
            do_something(i, j);
        }

    //  Done, put final code here.
}
```